# Extract Word OLE object in MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-word, office-interop, ole

I have an C# Project with an Microsoft Access Database. Inside the Table I have a Column with attached OLE Objects (Word Files). Solution is - open this attached Word Files from Database with C#. Found in the Internet so many Examples with Images, but no Example with an Word File.

I tried this, but it did not work. Any help?

```
string strSQL = "SELECT Attach FROM tbl_example WHERE ID=1";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, con);

var oleBytes = (Byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
const int offset = 85;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(oleBytes, offset, oleBytes.Length - offset);

Word.Application newWordApp = new Word.Application();
newWordApp.Visible = true;
Word.Document newWordDoc = newWordApp.Documents.Open(ms);
```

Comment: Is your current posted code doesn't work?

Comment: Ah sorry... yes the last Code line not work. It is not possible to take MemoryStream and make an Word.Dociment....

Answer (score 0):

I am re-design the code. 
Now with this example - the OLE word document will be read and will saved. When i will double clicked to open the saved word document on folder test - first word application open and bring me the message, the word file is corrupt. Then i press OK button and the document will be open... with all text and pictures are saved as OLE object in the database. So it will work now 99% :D ... this code works, no stop at debugging. but the new saved word file (from access ole db) is a little bit corrupt...

```
        string strSQL = "SELECT Anhang FROM tbl_inhalte WHERE ID=1";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, con);
        var oleBytes = (Byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test\worddatei.docx", oleBytes.Skip(0).ToArray());
```